# Shooting bullet towards mouse position in Java/Slick2D

Tags: java, math, mouseevent, slick2d

I'm trying to implement a method for shooting a bullet towards the mouse position. I don't know the math or the logic for it. It's a 2D top-down game. I have the bullet firing to the right and ending at a certain point. I need to know the logic for firing towards the mouse position, rather than just adding 1 to the x position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use atan2 to find the angle between the origin of the bullet and the mouse cursor. Then use Sin and Cos to calculate the x and y velocity of the bullet.

psuedo-code

```
    public void ShootBullet()
    {
        double bulletVelocity = 1.0; //however fast you want your bullet to travel
        //mouseX/Y = current x/y location of the mouse
        //originX/Y = x/y location of where the bullet is being shot from
        double angle = Math.Atan2(mouseX - originX, mouseY - originY);
        double xVelocity = (bulletVelocity) * Math.Cos(angle);
        double yVelocity = (bulletVelocity) * Math.Sin(angle);
    }
```

Comment: Love the simplicity of your answer lol. Im gonna try this out rn

Comment: It doesnt work. It will only shoot the bullet in a certain position and when it shoots the xvel and yvel will change if I move my mouse in a certain place

Comment: Isnt Cos and Sin for 2d sidescrollers?

Comment: instead of constantly grabbing the mouseX/Y just grab them at the instant you fired the bullet and then store them for future calculations. I'm not sure what you mean by 'it will only shoot the bullet in a certain position' are you refering to the location of where the bullet comes from?

Comment: it doesn't matter if its a sidescroller or a top down game, if its a 2D game you only care about 2 dimensions, so it will work for both.

Comment: It fire at only 3 angles. It wont shoot in between them

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for spawning the projectiles.

```
    public void spawnProjectile(Input input) {

    double mouseX = 0;
    double mouseY = 0;
    double xVel;
    double yVel;
    double angle;

    if (timer > 0) {
        timer--;
    }

    if (input.isMouseButtonDown(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON)) {
        mouseX = input.getMouseX();
        mouseY = input.getMouseY();
        if (projectiles.size() < 1 && timer <= 0) {
            projectiles.add(new Projectile((int) x + 8, (int) y + 8, 8, 8));
        }
    }

    if (projectiles.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
            projectiles.get(i).update(input);
            double originX = x;
            double originY = y;

            angle = Math.atan2(mouseX - originX, mouseY - originY);
            xVel = (bulletVel) * Math.cos(angle);
            yVel = (bulletVel) * Math.sin(angle);

            projectiles.get(i).x += xVel;
            projectiles.get(i).y += yVel;

            if (projectiles.get(i).timer == 0) {
                projectiles.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```